# How to add secondary text in elm?

Tags: elm

I have a dropdown which shows text as moredetails with a keyboard-down-arrow, on clicking it expands and i can see the required fields. What i am trying to achieve is once on clicking the button when the secondary field expands i want to change the text to 'less details', i am able to achieve till like on expansion the keyboard downarrow mark becomes keyboard up arrow mark.
this is my code

```
Html.span 
   [ Attributes.class "details" ]
   [ Html.a
      [ Attributes.href "#", Events.onClick (ExpandDetails tx.id)]
      [ Html.text "More detail"
      , Html.i 
          [ Attributes.class "material-icons" ]
          [ if expanded then
               Html.text "keyboard_arrow_up"
            else
               Html.text "keyboard_arrow_down"
          ]
      ]
   ]
```

i am able to make it till if expands show downarrow but along with it i need text to change from more details to less details and on clicking less details it should be back to more details.

Comment: See also https://discourse.elm-lang.org/t/how-to-pass-two-text-values-in-html-text/7079 for the same question with some additional answers.

Comment: You should select an answer, both for the people who took the time to help yopu and to help those who will meet the same problem as you.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could define both the button and text in a [`let` expression](https://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#let-expressions) before the dropdown code. Something like:

```
    let
        ( dropdownButton, dropdownText ) =
            if expanded then
                ( "keyboard_arrow_up", "Less details" )

            else
                ( "keyboard_arrow_down", "More details" )
    in
    Html.span [ Attributes.class "details" ]
        [ Html.a
            [ Attributes.href "#"
            , Events.onClick (ExpandDetails tx.id)
            ]
            [ Html.text dropdownText
            , Html.i [ Attributes.class "material-icons" ]
                [ Html.text dropdownButton ]
            ]
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative.

Move the link into a function that takes the `String`s as arguments.

```
viewDetails : Tx -> Bool -> Html Msg
viewDetails tx expanded =
    let
        lessOrMoreLink =
            if expanded then
                viewExpandLink "Less" "keyboard_arrow_up"
            else
                viewExpandLink "More" "keyboard_arrow_down"
    in
    Html.span
        [ Attributes.class "details" ]
        [ lessOrMoreLink tx.id ]


viewExpandLink : String -> String -> Int -> Html Msg
viewExpandLink txt arrow id =
    Html.a
        [ Attributes.href "#"
        , Events.onClick (ExpandDetails id)
        ] 
        [ Html.text (txt ++ " details")
        , Html.i
            [ Attributes.class "material-icons" ]
            [ Html.text arrow ]
        ]
```